# Approach for having multiple users watch a video in sync with each other?

Tags: video

We have a system were committees need to discuss and evaluate videos.  Right now each committee member watches videos online separately, but what they really want is the ability to all watch "in sync" while participating in a conference call (the conference call does not need to be part of the solution).  So they'd all go to a given page to watch the video, and a presenter would start the video, pause the video as needed during discussion, etc., and each participant would see the video as the presenter controls it.

If anybody has an leads for me around code or tools that would help with building something like this, I'd appreciate it.  Our current stack is predominantly ColdFusion (which means we can load Java libraries as well), SQL Server, and jQuery, but I'd be open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Jim